# after i delete conflicting files, the merge doesn't realise files in source branch to merge

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I try to merge master to my branch but there are some conflicts. I delete the conflicting files in my branch and try to merge again but it says "Already up to date."

The files I want to merge in the master branch are still there. Those files I want to merge to my branch don't show up but the commit and merge keep saying "Already up to date."

Please help and explain the situation as I am new at git.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting those files on your branch was probably a mistake. You've had a content conflict (I changed line 123 from "foo" to "bar", and they changed line 123 from "foo" to "omg") into an existence conflict (they change line 123 from "foo" to "omg", and I say: delete the whole file).

However, it's strange that you get "Already up to date." when merging now. It seems that you have not said everything about what you did there. You'd get "Already up to date." only when master branch is considered to be already fully merged into your branch.Judgding from what you say, you must have deleted the files, and then committed that change (file deletion) as the conflict resolution. If you have done that, then the history looks like this:

before:

```
              changeA - changeB - changeC[yourwork] --- (merge conflict)
            /                                          /
some common                                          / 
   state    \                                      /
              changeX - changeY - changeZ[master]
```

after:

```
              changeA - changeB - changeC ---- (merge+deletefiles)[yourwork]
            /                                        /
some common                                         /
   state    \                                      /
              changeX - changeY - changeZ[master]
```

In this state, trying to merge master does nothing, because it was already merged, hence "Already up to date" message. Also, on `yourwork` branch the files are missing, since you deleted them. And on master they are still present, since on `master` there's no commit that deletes those files.

Fun fact: if you now merge your branch into master, the files will be gone from master as well.

Probably the best way to resolve this would be to undo the merge commit (i.e. `reset` your branch to `changeC` and redo the merge; or `revert` the `merge+deletefiles` commit and redo the merge).

When you redo the merge, either way, you will get again the same conflict as before. This time, you should `resolve` the conflicts: tell git which version of files you want to keep (instead of telling git you don't want those files at all).